# Spring boot not able to get secrets from Google secret manager during deployment in GCP

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, gcp-secret-manager

I have a Spring-boot based micro-service which is getting the database URL and credentials from GCP secret manager. I was able to run the service on my local and the secrets were being fetched from GCP secret manager without any error.
I have also configured circleCI to deploy the application to GCP portal. But during the deployment, I can see that the service is not fetching the secrets fro Secret manager but instead trying to use the provided strings as username and password.
My application.properties file looks like following:-

```
spring.cloud.gcp.secretmanager.enabled=true
spring.config.import=sm://
server.port=8000

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${sm://projects/sandbox-dev-rotw-316c/secrets/ms-java-database-host-dev}:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=${sm://projects/sandbox-dev-rotw-316c/secrets/ms-java-database-username-dev}
spring.datasource.password=${sm://projects/sandbox-dev-rotw-316c/secrets/ms-java-database-password-dev}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Any reason why this would work on local and not on GCP portal?

Comment: How do you deploy? What's the permission of your runtime service account? Do you have error entries in the logs?

Comment: The deployment is happening using  a docker file. I think the credentials are not getting set in the docker container. Will confirm and respond